# Best Practice in Rails 3.2: Attach javascript functions to window object?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, view, javascript-namespaces

I have a rails application where a lot of views are rendered in javascript (i.e. rendered from remote actions).  After rails compiles my coffee script files into javascript I am finding that, due to namespace separation I believe, these views cannot reference any javascript functions unless I attach the functions to the window object.  E.g.

```
window.finishEditingNode = ->
    $("#this_area").hide(1000)
    $("#that_form").show(1000)
```

This is what I have been doing but it doesn't seem right to be attaching virtually even function to the window object.  Is there a better way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Attach a context to window, and define anything under that context.